# Simbad requires Java 3D

Tags: classpath, setup-deployment, java-3d

Context:

- MS Windows 8,
- jre7 preinstalled by MS Windows setup,
- MS Windows PATH environment variable has set to JRE7 bin folder - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin,
- [simbad-1.4.jar](http://simbad.sourceforge.net/) is downloaded into a local folder.

Use cases:

- simbad-1.4.jar is run by command line

  java -jar simbad-1.4.jar
- or by just double-clicking on simbad-1.4.jar

In both cases

```
Simbad requires Java 3D
```

error message box appears.

Yes, I know, setting-up [Java 3D](http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html) should probably fix the issue but I'd like to just deliver/setup Java 3D together with/in a subfolder to simbad-1.4.jar IOW to not install Java 3D into a standard C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\Java3D location.

Please advise how can I setup Java 3D packaged together with simbad-1.4.jar, or answer a more general question:

- *How to deploy a Java client application, which uses Java 3D, packaged together with Java 3D library?*

P.S. I know about and I have used -classpath option to successfully run other sample java client apps' .jar(s) I have made exported by using Eclipse but they haven't used nor Java 3D nor simbad-1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a slightly different environment (Win7-64bit, JDK 1.7), but this should work for your environment also.

1. download java3d .zip package from https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html
2. unzip the downloaded file, and there's is another zip file named "j3d-jre.zip"
3. unzip 'j3d-jre.zip' in a directory you want to package together.
4. place simbad jar file in that directory.
5. create a DOS batch file with these lines in it:

```
    @echo off
    set CLASSPATH=.;.\lib\ext\j3dcore.jar;.\lib\ext\j3dutils.jar;.\lib\ext\vecmath.jar;.\simbad-1.4.jar
    set PATH=%PATH%;.\bin
    java -classpath %CLASSPATH% simbad.gui.Simbad
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This version of Java3D is obsolete, you can find some information about Java3D maintained by the JogAmp community in our wiki: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Java3D